# toggle function not working properly in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

[image]

[image]

as you can see from the above images my toggle function is working properly on 1st post but it doesn't work on 2nd post my code goes like this

```
<input type="submit" name="submitcomment" value="comment" id="comment"></div><hr>
<div id="commentbody" style="display:none;"><input type="text" name="postcomment"></div>
```

and my jquery code goes like this

```
$('#comment').click(function()
{
    $('#commentbody').toggle();
});
```

how to make toggle function working on all the posts

Comment: Did you really mean `#comment` to be a **submit** button?

Comment: If you could recreate a working sample of the issue it would be great ! (including some images, using [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/)).

Comment: use class, id is the problem there.

Comment: id targets one element. class targets all.

Comment: @Zeratops: These days, Stack Snippets rather than jsFiddle where possible.

Comment: someone else answered, just like i said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you can't have the same ID more than once on a page, so **both** of those elements need to be identified in some other way.

I would use classes, and then:

```
$('.comment').click(function()
{
    $(this).nextAll(".commentbody").first().toggle();
});
```

**Live Example:**

```js
$('.comment').click(function()
{
    $(this).nextAll(".commentbody").first().toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="submit" name="submitcomment" value="comment" class="comment"><hr>
<div class="commentbody" style="display:none;"><input type="text" name="postcomment"></div>
<input type="submit" name="submitcomment" value="comment" class="comment"><hr>
<div class="commentbody" style="display:none;"><input type="text" name="postcomment"></div>
<input type="submit" name="submitcomment" value="comment" class="comment"><hr>
<div class="commentbody" style="display:none;"><input type="text" name="postcomment"></div>
```

---

Note: Your markup example contained an errant `</div>` after the `#comment` element, which I removed above. **If** `#comment` is inside a `div` you didn't show the beginning of, the content of the handle will need to use `.parent()`:

```
$('.comment').click(function()
{
    $(this).parent().nextAll(".commentbody").first().toggle();
});
```

**Live Example:**

```js
$('.comment').click(function()
{
    $(this).parent().nextAll(".commentbody").first().toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><input type="submit" name="submitcomment" value="comment" class="comment"></div><hr>
<div class="commentbody" style="display:none;"><input type="text" name="postcomment"></div>
<div><input type="submit" name="submitcomment" value="comment" class="comment"></div><hr>
<div class="commentbody" style="display:none;"><input type="text" name="postcomment"></div>
<div><input type="submit" name="submitcomment" value="comment" class="comment"></div><hr>
<div class="commentbody" style="display:none;"><input type="text" name="postcomment"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you have duplicate IDs. IDs should be always unique. `$('#comment')` will only target first element with id comment. Due to which event is not attached to second element.

You can rather give same class(say `comment`) to submit buttons and other class (say `commentbody`) to div `commentbody`:

```
<div><input type="submit" name="submitcomment" value="comment" class="comment"></div><hr>
<div class="commentbody" style="display:none;"><input type="text" name="postcomment"></div>
```

and then use class selector to bind event and target next commentbody div:

```
$('.comment').click(function(){
 $(this).parent().nextAll('.commentbody').first().toggle();
            //or
 $(this).parent().nextAll('.commentbody').eq(0).toggle();
});
```

Comment: That will always toggle the *same* commentbody.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have multiple elements with the same IDs. Try to generate a unique ID for each of the comment button and comment body.

```
$('#comment').click(function()
{
    $('#commentbody').toggle();
});

$('#comment1').click(function()
{
    $('#commentbody1').toggle();
});
```

I would not recommend using IDs. The proper way of doing this in my opinion is giving all the buttons the same class, and a data-target attribute, and giving the comment bodies a unique ID.

```
<button class='commentBtn' data-target='commentBody1'>
<button class='commentBtn' data-target='commentBody2'>
<div id='commentBody1'>
<div id='commentBody2'>

<script>
$('.commentBtn').click(function(){
  var target = $(this).data('target');
  $('#'+target).toggle();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Id should be unique in a page , you cannot have multiple elements with same id in one page. In your case you can do something like below (instead of **id** use **class**)

```
<div>
    <input type="button" name="submitcomment" value="comment" class="comment">
</div>
<div class="commentbody" >
     <input type="text" name="postcomment">
</div>
```

And you JS code is as follows:-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".comment").click(function() {
        $(this).parent().next(".commentbody").toggle();
    });
});
```

Hope this will help you. Good luck